# How to get a input value onChange in react variable?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a search text box I need to get the value onchange send the request to API when I use the normal event.target method it shows error. how to rectify it as in onchange I need to call a function with some arguments so I cannot go by ease.

my text box is :

```
<input className="ReactSearchBox" name="search" placeholder="Search Doctors" 
          onClick={() => {
            this.onProviderListing(this.state.skip,0);
            this.onEnable();
                  }}
          onChange={() =>this.onSearchProvider(this.state.skip,0)} />
```

my function where i need the onchange value is:

```
onSearchProvider(nSkip,nLimit,e){
      this.setState({
        limit:nLimit,
        skip:nSkip,
        listing: this.state.listing,
        searching: !this.state.searching
      })
      //console.log(nlimit);
      var headers = {
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "AccessToken":localStorage.TOKEN,
      }
      var _calObj = {initiatorId:localStorage.userid,visitType: "office", skip:nSkip,limit:"5", includeOfflineProviders:"true",searchQuery:"lo"}
```

I need to give my input values in search query onchange correspondingly, sort it out plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing event from input. Change the onChange prop to:

```
       <input className="ReactSearchBox" name="search"
          placeholder="Search Doctors" 
          onClick={() => {
            this.onProviderListing(this.state.skip,0);
            this.onEnable();
                  }}
          onChange={(e) =>this.onSearchProvider(this.state.skip,0, e)}
        />

onSearchProvider(nSkip,nLimit,e){
  const value = e.target.value; // text box value 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update the `onChange` in jsx by passing the `e` event object also like:

```
onChange={(e) => this.onSearchProvider(this.state.skip,0,e)}
```

and in `onSearchProvider` you can access it like:

```
onSearchProvider(nSkip, nLimit, {target}){
   // you can see search box text here on change
   console.log(target.value) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass state values on onChange method call.

> **State will be consistent throughout component.**

```
<input className="ReactSearchBox" name="search" placeholder="Search Doctors" 
     onChange={() =>this.onSearchProvider(0)}
/>
```

And you can get value from event of that input as `event.target.value`

```
onSearchProvider(nLimit,e){
  // access your state values directly here like this.state.skip
  const searching = e.target.value;
}
```